# Like Box works for users logged into FB - but not otherwise

Tags: facebook

I have a weird problem that I cannot get my FB Like box to show up in Chrome, Chrome Incognito / Firefox / Opera it just doesn't render at all. It shows up just fine if I log in to Facebook first.

Inside `<head>`:

```
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=409074972499544";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

After opening tag of `<body>`

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
```

Located at the where I want the box to be rendered at:

`<div style="padding-bottom: 10px;"><fb:like-box href="https://www.facebook.com/LeagueOfLegendsFinland" width="250" show_faces="false" colorscheme="dark" stream="false" header="false"></fb:like-box></div>`

My FB App: [image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2188345/fb.jpg]

So any experienced dev there who could point out my mistake? :) I already tried the HTML5/Iframe versions but it's the same deal. Also tried moving the code just right before body closes.

Oh, if anyone wants to directly go inspect the page: http://leagueoflegends.fi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

> If the Like box won't display content to logged-out users, it's almost
>   certainly because there's a demographic restriction on your page. The
>   API (and social plugins) will only return information about such pages
>   to users who meet the restrictions.
>
> It's most likely that you've not yet published the page, have marked
>   the page as being for users >18, for users in a certain country, or
>   have marked the page as being 'Alcohol related' (which limits it to
>   users of legal drinking age in their country)

Had a country restriction on the page itself.

Answer (score 1):

Check your page dat if there is any restrictions.It happens because of the restrictions we made. Age restrictions,country something like that. Just remove that restrictions,it will works fine.
Use any iframe fb box or javascript.It wrks fine.